# Are some steps wrong in this derivation (Kronig Penney Model)?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig.E2.80.93Penney_model), Wikipedia has the derivation for the equation:

$$\cos(ka)=\cos(\alpha a) + P \frac{\sin(\alpha a)}{\alpha a}$$

I didn't understand one of the steps:
[image]

$\beta^2-\alpha^2$ should be equal to $\frac{2m(V_o-2|E|)}{\hbar^2}$ and not $\frac{2m(V_o)}{\hbar^2}$. I don't understand how they managed to come up with $P=\frac{mV_o ba}{\hbar^2}$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos(ka)=\cos(\beta b)\cosh[\alpha(a-b)]+\frac{\beta^2-\alpha^2}{2\alpha\beta}\sin(\beta b)\sinh[\alpha(a-b)]$$
$$\cos(ka)=\cos(\beta b)\cosh[\alpha(a-b)]+\frac{\beta^2(1-\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2})b}{2\alpha}\frac{\sin(\beta b)}{\beta b}\sinh[\alpha(a-b)]$$

Approximate for $b\to 0\quad\implies\quad\beta\to\infty\quad;\quad \beta b\to 0\quad$ (See the page in Wikipedia) :

$\frac{\sin(\beta b)}{\beta b}\to 1 \quad ;\quad 1-\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\to 1$

$$\cos(ka)\simeq\cos(\beta b)\cosh[\alpha(a-b)]+\frac{\beta^2 b}{2\alpha}\sinh[\alpha(a-b)]$$

$\cosh[\alpha(a-b)]\to\cosh(\alpha a) \quad ;\quad  \sinh[\alpha(a-b)]\to\sinh(\alpha a)$
$$\cos(ka)\simeq\cos(\beta b)\cosh(\alpha a)+\frac{\beta^2 b}{2\alpha}\sinh(\alpha a)$$
$\beta b\to 0 \implies \cos(\beta b)\to 1\quad$ See the page in Wikipedia.
$$\cos(ka)\simeq\cosh(\alpha a)+\frac{\beta^2 b}{2\alpha}\sinh(\alpha a)$$
$$\cos(ka)\simeq\cosh(\alpha a)+\frac{\beta^2 ba}{2}\frac{\sinh(\alpha a)}{\alpha a} = \cosh(\alpha a)+P\frac{\sinh(\alpha a)}{\alpha a}$$
$$P=\frac{\beta^2 ba}{2}$$
$\beta^2=\frac{2m(V_0-|E|)}{\hbar^2}= \frac{2mV_0(1-\frac{|E|}{V_0})}{\hbar^2} \to \frac{2mV_0}{\hbar^2}$
$$P\simeq\frac{2mV_0}{\hbar^2}\frac{ ba}{2} = \frac{mV_0 ab}{\hbar^2}$$